# How to convert timestamp with time zone to numeric (unix) in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, date

I have timestamps with time zone (timestamptz) in my table. Can I convert them to numeric or int in unix timestamp format?

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155683/convert-timestamp-without-timezone-to-integer-postgres), but it shows only how to convert timestamp without time zone to unix timestamp.

Answer (score 5):

To solve this, I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45913429/470530).

For example, I'm in a time zone which is at UTC + 1,

so,

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

gives:

```
2019-06-06 17:41:00.216647
```

which is 1 hour behind clock time because I'm on UTC + 1.

So, then from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27740454/470530), I got `SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ts) FROM data`

Combining the two gives:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'));
```

which for me gives:

```
date_part
1559843103.53928
```

YMMV - fiddle available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=56b317795b75d90bc46247dc9420f6f7) - put your timestampz into the formula for current_timestamp and you should be golden!

Interstingly, you can check your results [here](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php).

p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The following returns numeric *without* decimal digits, if that is preferred:

```
select extract(epoch from current_timestamp)::integer;
```

Comment: @JohnK.N. The explicit cast to integer is different?

Comment: `select (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM created_at) * 1000000)::bigint` to get nanoseconds